# Colon before list. What is used after the list?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

If my list is at the middle of sentence:

> 3 proteins: albumin (ALB), catalase (CAT), and epidermal growth factor (EGF)*** were digested with enzymes and mixed with ...

, what should I use at ***?

Comment: Why would there need to be anything there? Your first two list items were nouns, there's no reason to think that "were digested..." belongs to the third item. It's clear from context that this is a continuation of the sentence.

Comment: Use of a colon to set off a list when used in apposition to a subject is probably unacceptable. Use a pair of dashes or brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No punctuation is needed there; however, it might be more clear to offset with dashes (since your list includes parentheses already):

> 3 proteins — albumin (ALB), catalase (CAT), and epidermal growth factor (EGF) — were digested with enzymes and mixed with ...

From [Write.com](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/punctuation/the-use-of-the-dash/):

> To replace colons or parentheses for emphasis
>
> If you want to place more emphasis on something that follows a colon or is contained within parenthesis, you can replace either with dashes. In a more formal piece, the colons or parentheses are used instead.
>
> **Colon:** Attendees must cover their own lodging costs—hotel room, food and beverages.
>
> **Parentheses:** The three couples—two who were married and one who was engaged—started group therapy.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't put anything there, but you could also end the list with a period and then start the next sentence with something like "These were digested..."